# Group items based on x number characters of basename

Tags: powershell, directory

I got help to setup a clever script that groups items in a folder based on basename and LastWriteTime it lets me delete everything except given number of files (i.e 5 versions). Now I'd like to limit basename grouping to 8 characters.

```
gci C:\test\ |
where{-not $_.PsIsContainer} |
$file = basename
Group-Object $file.substring(8) |
foreach {
  $_.Group |
  sort LastWriteTime -Descending |
  Select -Skip 5 |
   foreach { Remove-Item $_.fullname -Force -WhatIf }
  }
```

As I'm really new to powershell I'm not sure if above is correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to group by the first 8 characters, you need `Substring(0, 8)`. `Substring(8)` will produce the substring from the 9th character to the end of the string. Also, if you want to group by properties of the current object, you define them in a scriptblock.

Change this:

```psh
gci C:\test\ |
where{-not $_.PsIsContainer} |
$file = basename
Group-Object $file.substring(8) | ...
```

into this:

```psh
Get-ChildItem 'C:\test' |
  Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} |
  Group-Object { $_.Basename.Substring(0,8) } | ...
```

Note that `Substring(0,8)` will throw an error if the basename is shorter than 8 characters. You can avoid that for instance by defining the length as the minimum of 8 and string length:

```psh
$_.Basename.Substring(0, [Math]::Min(8, $_.Basename.Length))
```

Comment: Avoid `Substring()` throwing errors with something like `Group-Object { if(($b = $_.Basename).Length -le 8){ $b } else { $b.Substring(0,8) } }`

Comment: That would be one option. Personally, I prefer `[Math]::Min()`, though.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers @Mathias R. Jessen
This works perfect however I now noticed that I have a set of files coming as:
`ABCDE.report.txt.zip`
Could you help me to add extra condition (if possible) to check something like if basename.Lenght is 5 then use next 8 charactes as basename?

Comment: @qubert The basename of `ABCDE.report.txt.zip` is `ABCDE.report.txt`.